# How to get the largest integer using modular programming?

Tags: c

So, I've been trying to get two integers from the user and the program should return the value of the larger one. Here is my sample program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int larger(int a, int b);
int main()
{
    int num1, num2;
    printf("Enter first number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num1);
    printf("Enter second number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num2);
    printf("\n%d is larger than the other", larger(num1, num2) );

}

int larger(int a, int b)
{
    if (a>b)
    {
        printf("%d", a);
    }
    else if(b>a){
        printf("%d", b);
    }

}
```

But the problem here is that whenever I compile then run the program an integer value of 1 is placed beside the sentence "is larger than the other" ,while the largest integer (the integer that should be beside the 'is larger than the other') is placed above the integer 1.

**SAMPLE OUTPUT:**

```
Enter first number: 5
Enter second number: 3
5
1 is larger than the other
```

What should I do to place the larger value placed where it should be?

Comment: Compile with all warnings enabled.

Answer (score 8):

```
int larger(int a, int b)
```

Your function doesn't have a `return` statement . If you want largest value between two you need to return it from function . Like this -

```
int larger(int a, int b)
{
   if (a>b)
   {
      //printf("%d", a);      unnecessary as you print value in main
      return a;
   }
  else if(b>a){
     //printf("%d", b);
     return b;
  }
  else 
      return a;  //in this case take care of output message as both variables will be equal
}
```

Comment: This is undefined behaviour on `a == b`. Fix that and I'll sportingly upvote you.

Comment: One less cat eaten by a standards-compliant compiler. Have an upvote.

Answer (score 4):

`larger` needs to actually return the larger value: write `return a;`, and `return b;` in the appropriate places. And the output will look odd if you retain the `printf` calls in that function.

Currently your program behaviour is **undefined** as the `return` value is missing: the output is currently arbitrary.

You're also not dealing with all possibilities. What should happen if `a` and `b` are equal? You **must** return something on all control paths.

Comment: "Functors" in generic programming are typically defined so that "larger" returns true if a is larger than b, otherwise they return false. Since the opposite of "larger" is "not larger", which also covers the equality case.

Comment: "if, and only if," would be better.

Answer (score 2):

Your function isn't returning anything, you need to enable compiler warnings or alternatively, get a new compiler.

That being said, in case you aren't afraid of boolean logic, the function can simply be written as

```
static inline bool larger (int a, int b)
{
  return a > b;
}
```

Naturally, you'll have to rewrite main() to check the result:

```
if(larger (x, y))
{
  printf("x larger than y");
}
```

Comment: Once you're no longer afraid of anything, just write `a > b` as an expression (which in C evalutes to 1 or 0) and ditch the function.

Comment: @Bathsheba But then you can no longer use it as a functor, to be passed to generic functions like bsearch, qsort etc. These kind of functions have their purpose.

Answer (score 0):

In int function `larger(int a, int b)` you should just compare and return the value rather than printing it.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int larger(int a, int b);

int main()
{
    int num1, num2, largeOftheTwo= 0;
    printf("Enter first number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num1);
    printf("Enter second number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num2);

    if(num1 != num2)
        printf("\n%d is larger than the other", larger(num1, num2));
    else
        printf("\n%d is equal to %d", num1, num2);

    return 0;
}


int larger(int a, int b)
{
    if (a>b)
        return a;
    else
        return b;
}
```